# TypeError: rzp.open is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am integrating Razorpay in my react website and I got this error at `rzp.open()`;

```
 openCheckout() {
    let options = {
      "key_id": "My_key", //I have used correct one
      "key_secret": "my_secret_key", // I have used correct one
      "amount": 2000, // 2000 paise = INR 20, amount in paisa
      "name": "Merchant Name",
      "description": "Purchase Description",
      "image": "/images/girl.jpg",
      "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
      },
      "prefill": {
        "name": "Harshil Mathur",
        "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
      },
      "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
      },
      "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
      }
    };
    
    let rzp = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp.open();
  }
```

//button i have used

Pay Rs 20

//I install razorpay using the command (npm install razorpay --save)

// and imported as (import Razorpay from 'razorpay')

// I have added script in index.html
//

Comment: Looks like there is no `open` function on razorpay instance, what are you looking to do?

Comment: I worte object options which contains key_id,key_secret ..... I think payment show proceed after calling rzp.open();     https://codepen.io/ankitstarski/pen/QgLXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have checkout(razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js) loaded into your page before openCheckout is executed. Can do it by adding it as a script tag in the HTML page of your app, or insert it dynamically.

You can also take a look at https://codepen.io/ankitstarski/pen/QgLXML.

```
class Checkout extends React.Component {
  state = {
    amount: 0
  };

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.changeAmount = this.changeAmount.bind(this);
    this.openCheckout = this.openCheckout.bind(this);
  }

  changeAmount(e) {
    this.setState({amount: e.target.value})
  }

  openCheckout() {
    let options = {
      "key": "YOUR_KEY_ID",
      "amount": this.state.amount, // 2000 paise = INR 20, amount in paisa
      "name": "Merchant Name",
      "description": "Purchase Description",
      "image": "/your_logo.png",
      "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
      },
      "prefill": {
        "name": "Harshil Mathur",
        "email": "harshil@razorpay.com"
      },
      "notes": {
        "address": "Hello World"
      },
      "theme": {
        "color": "#F37254"
      }
    };

    let rzp = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp.open();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' onChange={
           this.changeAmount
          } />
        <button onClick={this.openCheckout}>Pay Rs. {this.state.amount/100}</button> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[razorpay](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node) on `npm` leads to the node bindings for the library.

The `open()` method as [shown in the docs](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/integrations-guide/checkout/standard/#manual-checkout) is on a different JavaScript library.

You can add it to your React app by appending:

```
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
```

to your `index.html` itself.

Comment: @RahulChoudhary Do you have the same error as earlier?

Comment: No, I am integrating razorpay for the first time

Comment: I am using it in reactjs (web) and i have installed it using command (npm i razorpay) and imported as (import Razorpay from "razorpay")

Comment: Like it says in my answer, razorpay npm package is not the one you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please tell me about the library which supports it. I have already added the script in index.html

Comment: just remove the import then

Comment: I am using Razorpay in react class

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more on adding the script and usage currently?